# Notice (1024): Element Not Found: Elements\default.ctp [CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 425

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to flash a message when a Topic is created. After the database was added it successfully redirected to index but doesn't flash a message instead I got this error. Below is my controller. I'm using cake cakephp2.x someone told me to put something on Elements.Please help me to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

> Notice (1024): Element Not Found: Elements\default.ctp
>   [CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 425

```
 <?php
 class TopicsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Session');
    public function index(){

    }
    public function add(){

        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->Topic->create();

            if($this->Topic->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash('Topic has been created!');
                $this->redirect('index');
            }
        }
    }

 }
?>
```

Comment: Please just check if you have the file default.ctp inside ``your_app\lib\Cake\View\Elements\Flash``. If not download them from here https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.8/lib/Cake/View/Elements/Flash and you probably be fine.

Comment: What version of CakePHP (2.what) and how are you rendering your flash messages? **Please edit the question to say/show**. If you're using `Session->setFlash`, it's expected you're using `Session->flash` in the layout

Comment: Hi I already have ctp's inside the lib\Cake\View\Elements\Flash

code inside was: 
<?php
$class = 'message';
if (!empty($params['class'])) {
    $class .= ' ' . $params['class'];
}
?>
<div id="<?php echo h($key) ?>Message" class="<?php echo h($class) ?>"><?php echo h($message) ?></div>

Comment: I'm using cakephp 2.7.3

Comment: @FatalError the above comment is not readable (and also not what I asked for -  the layout snippet is what matters). Perhaps you can help me to understand how I can get the authors of questions to put stuff like that in the question instead of comments? Writing in bold doesn't seem to work. Props for answering your own question - don't forget to accept it when you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks I already notice that session component is not used anymore in cakephp 2.7+,  and flash component should be a replacement.
so I change my code

```
 public $components = array('Session');
```

to

```
 public $components = array('Flash');
```

and

```
 $this->Session->setFlash('Topic has been created!');
```

to

```
 $this->Flash->set('The Topic has been created!');
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Just to clarify your comment: Session component is still in use - it has not been removed. Since version 2.7 only the Flash methods have been removed from the Session component.

Answer (score 0):

Before:

\lib\Cake\View\Elements\Flash\default.ctp

copy de default.ctp in the Elements Folder

\lib\Cake\View\Elements\default.ctp

Should work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Copy 
   `default.ctp`  file from this directory in your computer in CakePHP setup folder

```
htdocs/cake/lib/Cake/View/Elements/Flash
```

and paste copy of `default.ctp` file outside Flash folder in Elements Folder.
at this location

```
htdocs/cake/lib/Cake/View/Elements
```

It will work great. 
I've tried it

Answer (score -1):

For Partial view of Default element included in Index.ctp or can through setFlash as default. so please include element ctp for avoid issue and get below output

// Will use `/app/Plugin/Comment/View/Elements/default.ctp`

```
$this->Session->setFlash(
    'Example message text',
    'default',
    array('class' => 'example_class')
);
```

Here `default` should be element and please ensure available of default element ctp

The output from using `$this->Session->flash()` with the above mentioned example would be:

`<div id="flashMessage" class="example_class">Example message text</div>`

To use an element from a plugin just specify the plugin in the $params:

// Will use `/app/Plugin/Comment/View/Elements/flash_no_spam.ctp`

```
$this->Session->setFlash(
    'Message!',
    'flash_no_spam',
    array('plugin' => 'Comment')
);
```

For ref please find the link below:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html

Comment: Hi, I already have the debugkit on View/Elements/default.ctp should I make another ctp inside elements?

Comment: @FatalError: Sure you can use another ctp Element like mentioned above as 'flash_no_spam' instead of default ctp.

Comment: I notice this on the update

SessionComponent::setFlash() has been deprecated. You should use FlashComponent instead.

I hope it can be of any help.